# How to resize quill editor to fit inside a <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

I want quill editor to automatically fit inside a parent `<div>` element.

I created `<div>` element, and inside it I created again a `<div>` element which would be a container for quill editor. Toolbar is created automatically. I resized the parent `<div>` element using css to `width:50%` and `height:50%`, I hoped that all the contents inside it (quill editor and toolbar), will fit inside it, but some portions of the quill editor comes out of the parent `<div>` element.

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- parent div element, in which quill editor should fit -->
<div id="parent" style="width:50%;height:70%;border:2px solid green">

<!-- Quill editor div -->
        <div id="editor">
        </div>

    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var tool = [[{ 'header': '1' }, { 'header': '2' }], [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }], ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'], [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }, { 'font': [] }, { 'align': [] }], ['image',]];
var option = {
        placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
        theme: 'snow',
        modules: {
            toolbar: tool
        },
        bounds:'#parent'
    };
var quill = new Quill('#editor', option);
```

I had put a green border around the parent div, and I found that editor was coming out of the borders. Please see the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

NOTE: I just want to keep the size of parent div fixed.
So, please tell what should I do?

EDIT: I uploaded the whole code(html file), on my server([HERE](http://tu.unaux.com/game.html)). Issue was still there. Please check it out, and you can view the whole code using 'inspect element'.

Comment: Your screenshot is not added properly.

Comment: I have reproduced your issue but its working fine. check your other CSS, May be causing this issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be specific to your setup. If you can provide a fiddle that would be great.

Comment: @jcruz I used almost the same code in fiddle, but there was not any issue(idk why), I just uploaded the whole code(html file), on my server, http://tu.unaux.com/game.html, the issue is still there. Please check it out, you can view the code using "inspect element".

Comment: @aryaman setting `height: auto;` to `.ql-container` and `.ql-editor` seems to fix the issue

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the toolbar. The size defines the dimension of the text container, but then the container itself is pushed down by the toolbar. So you should set both the height of the parent div and of the editor div, making the first large enough to accommodate the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

Was this issue solved? I ran into the same issue today, I figured it out that the `#editor` has the height attribute which was set by default 100%, so I wrapped the `#editor` inside a container div and set a height for that div using pixel unit.

In case anyone might run into the same issue, you guys should try my solution, hope this help:

**HTML**

```
<div class="editor-container">
    <div id="editor">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editor-container {
    height: 300px; // Replace 300px = any number you want
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the Quill toolbar is not subtracted from the total component height. Try the following:

```
.ql-container {
  height: calc(100% - 42px); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is accurate

Comment: Might have to add !important in external CSS

Answer (score 0):

***.css:**

```
.editor-layout {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: blue;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px; //fix bug here
}
```

***.html:**

```
<div class="editor-layout">
  <div id="editor">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```